# Prove that $((a, b), b) = (a, b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can one prove that $((a,b),b)=(a,b)$?

What I have so far:

$((a, b), b) = (a, b)$ tells us that $(a, b)\mid (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \mid b$

Any help would be great.

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 5):

This is an immediate consequence of a result you asked about today. Using different symbols it asked to show that if $x$ divides $y$ and $x$ is positive then $(x,y)=x$.

Now set $x=(a,b)$ and $y=b$.

Answer (score 3):

$(a,b)$ divides both: $b$ and itself. It remains to show that if $m | (a,b)$ and $m| b$, then $m \le (a,b)$. This is really straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $(a,b)$ divides both itself and $b$, so the great common divisor of $(a,b)$ and $b$ is at least $(a,b)$. In other notation, $((a,b),b) \geq (a,b)$.

Now assume for contradiction that $((a,b),b)$ is strictly greater than $(a,b)$. Let the integer $k$ denote $((a,b),b)$, where $k > (a,b)$ and $k$ divides $(a,b)$. Then $k$ also divides $(a,b) * \frac{a}{(a,b)}$ since $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ is an integer. But $(a,b) * \frac{a}{(a,b)} = a$, which means that $k$ divides $a$. Furthermore, we already know that $k$ divides $b$. That means that $k$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$ that is greater than $(a,b)$, contradicting the fact that $(a,b)$ should be the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Hence we conclude that $((a,b),b) \leq (a,b)$.

Since $((a,b),b) \geq (a,b)$ and $((a,b),b) \leq (a,b)$, we have that $((a,b),b) = (a,b)$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it in easier way :

suppose $((a, b),b)=d~\quad and~ \quad (a,b)=d'$

then $d\mid(a,b)~and~d\mid b$
$\implies d\mid d'$

again $d'\mid a~and~ d'\mid b$
$\implies d'\mid (a,b)~and~d'\mid b$

$\implies d'\mid((a,b),b) \implies d'\mid d$

So we get $d\mid d'~and~d'\mid d$ and hence $d=d'$ $i.e.$ $((a, b),b)=(a,b)$